# XGBoost - Poisson distribution with varying exposure / offset

Tags: r, offset, poisson, xgboost

I am trying to use XGBoost to model claims frequency of data generated from unequal length exposure periods, but have been unable to get the model to treat the exposure correctly. I would normally do this by setting log(exposure) as an offset - are you able to do this in XGBoost?

(A similar question was posted here: [xgboost, offset exposure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896004/xgboost-offset-exposure))

To illustrate the issue, the R code below generates some data with the fields:

- x1, x2 - factors (either 0 or 1)
- exposure - length of policy period on observed data
- frequency - mean number of claims per unit exposure
- claims - number of observed claims ~Poisson(frequency*exposure)

The goal is to predict frequency using x1 and x2 - the true model is: frequency = 2 if x1 = x2 = 1, frequency = 1 otherwise.

Exposure can't be used to predict the frequency as it is not known at the outset of a policy. The only way we can use it is to say: expected number of claims = frequency * exposure.

The code tries to predict this using XGBoost by:

1. Setting exposure as a weight in the model matrix
2. Setting log(exposure) as an offset

Below these, I've shown how I would handle the situation for a tree (rpart) or gbm.

```
set.seed(1)
size<-10000
d <- data.frame(
  x1 = sample(c(0,1),size,replace=T,prob=c(0.5,0.5)),
  x2 = sample(c(0,1),size,replace=T,prob=c(0.5,0.5)),
  exposure = runif(size, 1, 10)*0.3
)
d$frequency <- 2^(d$x1==1 & d$x2==1)
d$claims <- rpois(size, lambda = d$frequency * d$exposure)

#### Try to fit using XGBoost
require(xgboost)
param0 <- list(
  "objective"  = "count:poisson"
  , "eval_metric" = "logloss"
  , "eta" = 1
  , "subsample" = 1
  , "colsample_bytree" = 1
  , "min_child_weight" = 1
  , "max_depth" = 2
)

## 1 - set weight in xgb.Matrix

xgtrain = xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(d[,c("x1","x2")]), label = d$claims, weight = d$exposure)
xgb = xgb.train(
  nrounds = 1
  , params = param0
  , data = xgtrain
)

d$XGB_P_1 <- predict(xgb, xgtrain)

## 2 - set as offset in xgb.Matrix
xgtrain.mf  <- model.frame(as.formula("claims~x1+x2+offset(log(exposure))"),d)
xgtrain.m  <- model.matrix(attr(xgtrain.mf,"terms"),data = d)
xgtrain  <- xgb.DMatrix(xgtrain.m,label = d$claims)

xgb = xgb.train(
  nrounds = 1
  , params = param0
  , data = xgtrain
)

d$XGB_P_2 <- predict(model, xgtrain)

#### Fit a tree
require(rpart)
d[,"tree_response"] <- cbind(d$exposure,d$claims)
tree <- rpart(tree_response ~ x1 + x2,
              data = d,
              method = "poisson")

d$Tree_F <- predict(tree, newdata = d)

#### Fit a GBM

gbm <- gbm(claims~x1+x2+offset(log(exposure)), 
           data = d,
           distribution = "poisson",
           n.trees = 1,
           shrinkage=1,
           interaction.depth=2,
           bag.fraction = 0.5)

d$GBM_F <- predict(gbm, newdata = d, n.trees = 1, type="response")
```

Answer (score 6):

At least with the `glm` function in R, modeling `count ~ x1 + x2 + offset(log(exposure))` with `family=poisson(link='log')` is equivalent to modeling `I(count/exposure) ~ x1 + x2` with `family=poisson(link='log')` and `weight=exposure`.  That is, normalize your count by exposure to get frequency, and model frequency with exposure as the weight.  Your estimated coefficients should be the same in both cases when using `glm` for Poisson regression.  Try it for yourself using a sample data set

I'm not exactly sure what `objective='count:poisson'` corresponds to, but I would expect setting your target variable as frequency (count/exposure) and using exposure as the weight in `xgboost` would be the way to go when exposures are varying.

Comment: Thanks Vinh. This is one of the options I had tried but didn't seem to work as expected in simple cases. I believe I have now found the solution and have posted it here.

Answer (score 4):

I have now worked out how to do this using setinfo to change the base_margin attribute to be the offset (as a linear predictor), ie:

```
setinfo(xgtrain, "base_margin", log(d$exposure))
```

Comment: so does this suffice for xgboost ? I mean, if you specify the base_margin, do you still have to specify weights in xgb.DMatrix? Thanks!

Comment: base_margin: base margin is the base prediction Xgboost will boost from ;
How do you propose , base_margin will work as an offset in traditional sense of Poisson problem?