# xgboost implementation in h2o offset

Tags: h2o, xgboost

I have been accustomed to use the base margin parameter in standard xgboost to allow for offset, starting (transformed) prediction (see this SO question [SO xgboost exposure question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896004/xgboost-offset-exposure). I wonder if it were possible to perform the same in the h2o implementation of xgboost. In particular I see an offset parameter, but I wonder wether it has been really truly implemented.

Comment: It is not supported at the moment. When used you should see an error ("Offset is not supported for XGBoost")

Comment: @Michal Kurka (H2O): yes, it is, at least in xgboost, only called otherwise: `setinfo(xgbMatrix, "base_margin", log(exposure))`; it has always been that way: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/681#issuecomment-297862691. Only H2O did not support it , favoring built-in GBM's (with offset). Has H2O fixed this by now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question -- this is not documented in the parameter description (we use a common definition of `offset_column` among all algos and there's no note about how its not working in XGBoost).  It is not functional and you should get an [error](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/feea76e0419c5acd3af98e2bf155811460561ca5/h2o-extensions/xgboost/src/main/java/hex/tree/xgboost/XGBoost.java#L120) if you try to supply it.

R example:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

fit <- h2o.xgboost(x = 1:3, y = "Species", offset_column = "Petal.Width",
                   training_frame = as.h2o(iris))
```

Gives error:

```
Error: water.exceptions.H2OModelBuilderIllegalArgumentException: Illegal argument(s) for XGBoost model: XGBoost_model_R_1520909592004_2.  Details: ERRR on field: _offset_column: Offset is not supported for XGBoost.
```

Comment: Hi Erin and Michal, thanks for your answer. Do you think it were possible to implement it in forthcoming releases?

Comment: Yes, as long as XGBoost supports this, we will add it later, but not in the next release.

Comment: Thanks, I have opened an issue in Atlassian